# How to create ApexClass record in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Here are many objects on which DML are not allowed in test class. But if our code is querying ApexClass sObject then how can we create some ApexClass records in test class to cover our code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApexClass` is a metadata object, not a standard sObject. Your actual, deployed Apex classes are visible in test context by querying `ApexClass`. Additionally, you cannot connect to the Metadata or Tooling APIs from test context to deploy a new class.

You can illustrate this for yourself with a simple example:

```
@isTest
public class TestQ237807 {
    @isTest public static void run() {
        System.debug([SELECT Name FROM ApexClass]);
    }
}
```

If you inspect the logs after running this test, you'll see all of your real `ApexClass` entries shown.

Note that this does result in some challenges with testing. Because the set of `ApexClass` records visible to your class may change, you need to ensure that the logic in your test class is resilient against such changes, since the data is not under your control.

The other option would be to adopt dependency injection and construct in-memory records instead of performing an actual query in test context. Then, you do have full control over the data your class sees, but you may have to do some rework of your code architecture.

Comment: Are you saying that you are or are not able to query `ApexClass` in test context? If no, do you receive an error, no results, or what? Can you please edit your code into your question?

Comment: Yes, It is working.

Comment: OK, so we're all good now? Deleting your comments is a little confusing.

Comment: Yes, Good for now.